# Oracle APEX show button when multiple conditions are met

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a couple of dropdowns on  my page, a hidden item and a button.

Whenever user changes the value of P1_DD1 or P1_DD2, I need to show the button if one of the following met:

1) If P1_HIDDEN='YES' and both P1_DD1 and P1_DD2 are not null

or

2) If P1_HIDDEN='NO' and P1_DD1 is not null

what is the best way to do this?

I originally added dynamic actions to both P1_DD1 and P1_DD2 on change and for P1_DD1 add set Client-side condition to Item IS NOT NULL and set the item to P1_DD1 and Server-side condition PL/SQL Ex[pression: `:P1_HIDDEN='NO'`

that works fine. The issue is with P1_DD2. I tried using similar logic - add client-side condition where P1_DD2 is not null and then add server-side condition PL/SQL Expression `:P1_HIDDEN='YES' AND P1_DD1 IS NOT NULL` but nothing happens. Trying to figure out why that is. Or, perhaps, there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1 - Try to create a dynamic action when these items change (P1_HIDDEN, P1_DD1, P1_DD2).

2 - Client Side Condition >> Javascript Expression

```
((apex.item('P1_DD1').getValue() != '') &&
(apex.item('P1_DD2').getValue() != '') &&
(apex.item('P1_HIDDEN').getValue() == 'YES'))
||
((apex.item('P1_DD1').getValue() != '') &&
(apex.item('P1_HIDDEN').getValue() == 'NO'))
```

3 - True Action >> Show your button >> enable execute when page load

4 - False Action >> Hide your button >> enable execute when page load

Comment: do you mean something like that: When

Event: Change
Selection Type; Item(s)
Items: P1_HIDDEN, P1_DD1, P1_DD2?

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for

Comment: You could probably clean this further with .isEmpty() https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeapi/apex-item.html#GUID-2F110B8D-18E6-4A50-A3BC-C61B38A0DA08

Answer (score 5):

Literally copying what you've written, button's condition (a function that returns Boolean) would look like this:

```
return (
         (    :P1_HIDDEN = 'YES' 
          and :P1_DD1 is not null
          and :P1_DD2 is not null
         )
         or
         (    :P1_HIDDEN = 'NO'
          and :P1_DD1 is not null
         )
       );
```

Comment: that is as a PL/SQL expression?

Comment: That's a *function body that returns Boolean value*. Apex automatically adds BEGIN and END so - you don't have to do it. If you do (and check debug), you'll see nested BEGIN-END blocks so that wouldn't be a mistake, but it isn't necessary.